# Resizing pre-installed and mounted raid partitions for LVM use

Tags: lvm, partition, raid1

Every time we order a new server from a new provider or even just with a new distro we run into inconsistencies. Meaning even though we go for a minimal distro the server will come with unwanted configurations. In this case I am talking about a server with 2x4TB HDDs that come pre-installed in a raid 1 configuration.
The raid also seems to be configured sensibly.
`lsblk`returns the following:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    16G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda3    8:3    0     2T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0     2T  0 raid1 /
├─sda4    8:4    0   1.7T  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0   1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sda5    8:5    0     1M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    16G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0     2T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0     2T  0 raid1 /
├─sdb4    8:20   0   1.7T  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0   1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sdb5    8:21   0     1M  0 part
```

As you can see the largest partition of 2TB is mounted at /.
This means it is currently housing and running most of the system.
Now, I plan to add a LVM abstraction layer to the server to have more/better control over my storage. I can of course not `umount /dev/md2` since it is busy.
So my question is: How do I properly and safely access the space (or some of it)  on `/dev/md2` in order to add it to my LVM configuration?
Is it even possible to have a logical volume mounted at `/` if it has not been configured during setup (due to image rather than manual install)? If so, how do I not lose data when mounting a LV at `/`, or more specifically how can I mount a LV on an already existing folder and "transfer" the data inside?
Am I missing something or going about it wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the provider provides you with a rescue-boot mode: go there, re-install the whole machine with the partitioning layout you desire.

If you already got data on the machine, you could order a new one, set it up properly and cycle data and services to the new one. Now re-install the first box and move data and services from another older box to this.
That's about the safest way I could imagine.

I got another idea - but this isn't nearly that safe:

take sdb out of the raid and set it up according to your partition scheme. Now mount all those partitions under /mnt (/mnt/boot, /mnt/home, etc), install a new system to /mnt (using debootstrap or similar) and transfer all data there. Setup grub to boot from sdb and reboot. Now do the same with sda and rebuild the raid from sdb to sda, reconfigure /etc/fstab to boot from md-nodes again and reboot. Cross fingers you did not forget ANYTHING! (this guide is nowhere near completeness, but should give you a hint how you could do this without a rescue-system)